# collect2: fatal error: cannot find ‘ld’ compilation terminated

Tags: g++

I has unfortunately  overridden the executable code in "/usr/bin/ld" So now ,when I run any c++ code try to execute it throws me and error
 collect2: fatal error: cannot find ‘ld’
compilation terminated.

So anybody please share me the code which is in "/usr/bin/ld"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should reinstall `ld` using the appropriate tools for your distribution. For example, for Debian-based distributions,

```
sudo apt install --reinstall binutils
```

and for Fedora-based distributions (including RHEL and CentOS),

```
sudo dnf reinstall binutils
```

or (for older versions)

```
sudo yum reinstall binutils
```

Comment: what about in mac

Comment: I’m afraid I have no idea.